# Qt 6.2.2 static Don't detect printers in windows

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries

I have been having an issue since upgrading to Qt6 my Qt static app don't detect printers on Qt 6 static on windows.

on mingw it complains that multimedia is not available.

on msvc2019 it compiles successfully but printerinfo printerslist is empty as no printers detected at all.

PS: it works fine on Qt 5.15.2 shared and static and qt 6 shared

msvc config

```
..\configure.bat -debug-and-release -opensource -confirm-license -opengl desktop -no-dbus -no-icu -no-fontconfig -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qt3d -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtcanvas3d -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtdatavis3d -skip qtdoc -skip qtgamepad -skip qtlocation -skip qtnetworkauth -skip qtpurchasing -skip qtremoteobjects -skip qtscxml -skip qtsensors -skip qtserialbus -skip qtserialport -skip qtspeech -skip qtquick3d -skip qtvirtualkeyboard -skip qtwebview -skip qtscript -qt-zlib -optimize-size -static -static-runtime -ltcg -nomake tools  -platform win32-msvc -c++std c++17 -sql-sqlite -sql-odbc -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -no-warnings-are-errors -no-sql-psql -make libs -prefix $prefix_folder -openssl-linked -- -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR="$openssl_base_folder" -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR="$openssl_include_folder"
```

mingw config

```
..\configure.bat -static-runtime -release -qt-doubleconversion -opensource -confirm-license -opengl desktop -nomake examples -nomake tests -nomake tools -static -platform win32-g++ -c++std c++17 -sql-sqlite -sql-odbc -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -no-warnings-are-errors -ssl -openssl-linked -no-sql-psql -optimize-size -skip qt3d -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtcanvas3d -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtdatavis3d -skip qtdoc -skip qtgamepad -skip qtlocation -skip qtnetworkauth -skip qtpurchasing -skip qtremoteobjects -skip qtscxml -skip qtsensors -skip qtserialbus -skip qtserialport -skip qtspeech -skip qtvirtualkeyboard -skip qtwebview -skip qtscript  -make libs  -prefix C:\Qt\6.2.2\mingw-x64-static-release -DOPENSSL_PREFIX="C:\Qt\6.2.2\mingw-x64-static-release\openssl" -DOPENSSL_LIBS="-llibssl -llibcrypto -luser32 -lcrypt32 -lws2_32 -lgdi32"
```

please is there somthing I could do to fix that or its a known issue and going to be fixed in the future.

My app is a personal app to take notes and save it and print it with just a sound notification if success ..

Comment: What differences are there for your Qt 6 shared vs. Qt 6 static configure lines? And if 6 shared is working, could you not simply use that?

Comment: for convinience only as I use it on multiple devices and updating a portable exe if far more easier and less bandwidth consuming as i use dropbox to share the app on multiple devices in windows

Comment: Fair enough -- I'd be carefully eyeing the differences between my configure lines for static vs. shared if I were you, sounds like the multimedia module may have gotten left out (or there's a bug with the static build config of the multimedia module). Have you checked the Qt bug lists yet? If not it may be worth filing one and seeing if anyone from Qt weighs in or can reproduce it.